# Zero-derived nouns in compound verbs

Tags: pronunciation, compounds

I recently read Wierzbicka 1984 (see [Bożena Cetnarowska 1993](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/197749102.pdf)) and I found this interesting footnote where she points out that some compound verbs of the form *have a(n) NP* require that the head noun of the deverbal NP be formally identical to the verb stem:

[image]

I was wondering if these kinds of contrasts are also seen with other cognate noun-verb pairs where the noun ends in the voiceless consonant and the verb in the voiced one (e.g. *excuse*, *house*, *mouth*, *breath*/*breathe*, *proof*/prove*, etc.). For instance, do you notice any variation in *take a breath*, *keep house*, and the like?

Comment: Which of those sentences in the example you provide are supposed to be valid? It seems to me like there are some asterisks missing.

Comment: They are all grammatical but mean different things. I've seen the examples cited in other scholarly works on compound predicates, e.g. Kate Kearns'.

Comment: "Have a choose" sounds completely wrong to me. Does this vary between dialects? (I'm in the US.)

Comment: I agree with alphabet's comment: some contexualizing explanation of what Wierzbicka says about the cited examples seems to be missing. "I want you to have a choose" and "Can I have a [ju:z] of your pen" both strike me as atypical wording, even if they are possible in some special specific circumstances.

Comment: Let's have a think. I've just had a thought: some transitive verbs have at least two nouns, one of them identical in form to the verb.

Comment: Random comments: 'I want to have a bath' does not require 'bathe'. / 'Proof' is a verb in its own right. // More structured reasoning: One can distinguish delexical (take a breath / ?have a choose ... informal / ...) from lexical (you have a choice / He had a [porcelain] bath / ...) usages. 'You have a choice' can hardly be analysed as including a 'compound verb'. On the other hand, 'have the use of' could be argued to be unary, a (cf Indian English 'avail') transitive multi-word verb.

Comment: Many candidate delexical structures ('Have an excuse' / 'Try a house [from V] on the immigrants' /  'Have a proof (= engage in providing a proof)' etc are simply unacceptable. Cetnarowska (above) examines idiomatic and barred examples of various verbo-nominal structures.

Comment: This is individual or small-group variation. "Grammatical" does not mean the same thing when not everybody talks the same.

Comment: For future reference, please Post text as text not, as here, as graphics and please don't include spurious phonetics. Could that work for you?

Comment: '… a choose…' and '… a use of your pen…' might work in some obscure dialect(s) but in general English they're almost always, simply wrong. 

In 60 years of listening, I've never once met '… a choose…' nor heard anyone say it might work.

'… a use of…' clearly is heard in some dialects but how does that justify its appearance here?